# The same usercontrol in all windows Forms of the same project C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Does anyone know how I can use the same UserControl (the content of the usercontrol, the same chosen color for example) I created in all windows Forms of the same project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: You could make a Window that contains the user control and inherit from this Window when you want to create another window. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what im looking for?